# Aligning Divs works in Firefox but not IE greater than 7

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, alignment

I am trying to migrate a web application to work with IE 11. When testing in IE 11, you'll see that the divs (each little green/blue box) don't line up properly. It looks perfectly fine in Firefox as you can see on jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/arramos84/x9wxcym4/).

Thanks for any help resolving this! Here's the code since it's required with the jsfiddle link:

**html**

```
  <h1>Matrix Test Page</h1>
  <div id="rack-0-bartok" title="rack-0">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="node node-faded" id="matrix-box-b017-bartok" style="background: #00DC00;" title="b017"></div>
      <div class="node node-faded" id="matrix-box-b018-bartok" style="background: #00DC00;" title="b018"></div>
      <div class="node node-faded" id="matrix-box-b019-bartok" style="background: #00DC00;" title="b019"></div>
      <div class="node node-faded" id="matrix-box-b020-bartok" style="background: #00DC00;" title="b020"></div>
      <div class="node node-faded" id="matrix-box-b021-bartok" style="background: #00DC00;" title="b021"></div>
      <div class="node node-faded" id="matrix-box-b022-bartok" style="background: #00DC00;" title="b022"></div>
      <div class="node node-faded" id="matrix-box-b023-bartok" style="background: #0000CD;" title="b023"></div>
      <div class="node node-faded" id="matrix-box-b024-bartok" style="background: #0000CD;" title="b024"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="node node-faded" id="matrix-box-b025-bartok" style="background: #0000CD;" title="b025"></div>
      <div class="node node-faded" id="matrix-box-b026-bartok" style="background: #0000CD;" title="b026"></div>
      <div class="node node-faded" id="matrix-box-b027-bartok" style="background: #0000CD;" title="b027"></div>
      <div class="node node-faded" id="matrix-box-b028-bartok" style="background: #00DC00;" title="b028"></div>
      <div class="node node-faded" id="matrix-box-b029-bartok" style="background: #00DC00;" title="b029"></div>
      <div class="node node-faded" id="matrix-box-b030-bartok" style="background: #00DC00;" title="b030"></div>
      <div class="node node-faded" id="matrix-box-b031-bartok" style="background: #0000CD;" title="b031"></div>
      <div class="node node-faded" id="matrix-box-b032-bartok" style="background: #0000CD;" title="b032"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="node node-faded" id="matrix-box-b001-bartok" style="background: #00DC00;" title="b001"></div>
      <div class="node node-faded" id="matrix-box-b002-bartok" style="background: #00DC00;" title="b002"></div>
      <div class="node node-faded" id="matrix-box-b003-bartok" style="background: #00DC00;" title="b003"></div>
      <div class="node node-faded" id="matrix-box-b004-bartok" style="background: #0000CD;" title="b004"></div>
      <div class="node node-faded" id="matrix-box-b005-bartok" style="background: #0000CD;" title="b005"></div>
      <div class="node node-faded" id="matrix-box-b006-bartok" style="background: #00DC00;" title="b006"></div>
      <div class="node node-faded" id="matrix-box-b007-bartok" style="background: #0000CD;" title="b007"></div>
      <div class="node node-faded" id="matrix-box-b008-bartok" style="background: #0000CD;" title="b008"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="node node-faded" id="matrix-box-b009-bartok" style="background: #00DC00;" title="b009"></div>
      <div class="node node-faded" id="matrix-box-b010-bartok" style="background: #00DC00;" title="b010"></div>
      <div class="node node-faded" id="matrix-box-b011-bartok" style="background: #00DC00;" title="b011"></div>
      <div class="node node-faded" id="matrix-box-b012-bartok" style="background: #00DC00;" title="b012"></div>
      <div class="node node-faded" id="matrix-box-b013-bartok" style="background: #0000CD;" title="b013"></div>
      <div class="node node-faded" id="matrix-box-b014-bartok" style="background: #0000CD;" title="b014"></div>
      <div class="node node-faded" id="matrix-box-b015-bartok" style="background: #00DC00;" title="b015"></div>
      <div class="node node-faded" id="matrix-box-b016-bartok" style="background: #00DC00;" title="b016"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="rack-1-bartok" title="rack-1">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="node node-faded" id="matrix-box-b049-bartok" style="background: #00DC00;" title="b049"></div>
      <div class="node node-faded" id="matrix-box-b050-bartok" style="background: #00DC00;" title="b050"></div>
      <div class="node node-faded" id="matrix-box-b051-bartok" style="background: #00DC00;" title="b051"></div>
      <div class="node node-faded" id="matrix-box-b052-bartok" style="background: #00DC00;" title="b052"></div>
      <div class="node node-faded" id="matrix-box-b053-bartok" style="background: #00DC00;" title="b053"></div>
      <div class="node node-faded" id="matrix-box-b054-bartok" style="background: #00DC00;" title="b054"></div>
      <div class="node node-faded" id="matrix-box-b055-bartok" style="background: #00DC00;" title="b055"></div>
      <div class="node node-faded" id="matrix-box-b056-bartok" style="background: #00DC00;" title="b056"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="node node-faded" id="matrix-box-b057-bartok" style="background: #00DC00;" title="b057"></div>
      <div class="node node-faded" id="matrix-box-b058-bartok" style="background: #0000CD;" title="b058"></div>
      <div class="node node-faded" id="matrix-box-b059-bartok" style="background: #0000CD;" title="b059"></div>
      <div class="node node-faded" id="matrix-box-b060-bartok" style="background: #0000CD;" title="b060"></div>
      <div class="node node-faded" id="matrix-box-b061-bartok" style="background: #00DC00;" title="b061"></div>
      <div class="node node-faded" id="matrix-box-b062-bartok" style="background: #0000CD;" title="b062"></div>
      <div class="node node-faded" id="matrix-box-b063-bartok" style="background: #0000CD;" title="b063"></div>
      <div class="node node-faded" id="matrix-box-b064-bartok" style="background: #0000CD;" title="b064"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="node node-faded" id="matrix-box-b033-bartok" style="background: #0000CD;" title="b033"></div>
      <div class="node node-faded" id="matrix-box-b034-bartok" style="background: #0000CD;" title="b034"></div>
      <div class="node node-faded" id="matrix-box-b035-bartok" style="background: #0000CD;" title="b035"></div>
      <div class="node node-faded" id="matrix-box-b036-bartok" style="background: #0000CD;" title="b036"></div>
      <div class="node node-faded" id="matrix-box-b037-bartok" style="background: #0000CD;" title="b037"></div>
      <div class="node node-faded" id="matrix-box-b038-bartok" style="background: #00DC00;" title="b038"></div>
      <div class="node node-faded" id="matrix-box-b039-bartok" style="background: #00DC00;" title="b039"></div>
      <div class="node node-faded" id="matrix-box-b040-bartok" style="background: #0000CD;" title="b040"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="node node-faded" id="matrix-box-b041-bartok" style="background: #00DC00;" title="b041"></div>
      <div class="node node-faded" id="matrix-box-b042-bartok" style="background: #00DC00;" title="b042"></div>
      <div class="node node-faded" id="matrix-box-b043-bartok" style="background: #0000CD;" title="b043"></div>
      <div class="node node-faded" id="matrix-box-b044-bartok" style="background: #00DC00;" title="b044"></div>
      <div class="node node-faded" id="matrix-box-b045-bartok" style="background: #0000CD;" title="b045"></div>
      <div class="node node-faded" id="matrix-box-b046-bartok" style="background: #0000CD;" title="b046"></div>
      <div class="node node-faded" id="matrix-box-b047-bartok" style="background: #0000CD;" title="b047"></div>
      <div class="node node-faded" id="matrix-box-b048-bartok" style="background: #00DC00;" title="b048"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

**css**

```
.row {
    background: #cccccf;
    margin: 0 !important;
}

div[id*='rack-'] {
    float: left;
    padding: 2px !important;
}

.node {
    width: 4px;
    height: 4px;
    float: left;
    border: 1px solid #B0B0B0;
    background: #cccccf;
    margin: 0 !important;
    cursor: pointer;
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);
    opacity: 1;
}

.faded .node-faded {
    width: 4px;
    height: 4px;
    filter: alpha(opacity=50);
    opacity: .5;
}
```

Comment: can you post a screenshot on your IE result? the only difference I can see on IE vs firefox, is IE displays all the boxes in one line, while firefox display boxes for each row, which can be fixed by adding ```clear:both;``` in ```.row``` class fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/x9wxcym4/4/

Comment: That's exactly the difference. I'm not a front-end guy, so I didn't know about clear. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, this is kinda weird, I added `height: 6px` to class `.row` and now it works in IE11+ (and FF DE44+, CH46+).

Did you try clearfix already? Should work with floats too.